# IBDesignable is not working in Xcode 11 beta generated xcframework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Image below is the .swiftinterface generated from the .xcframework. Is there anyone with succession on this issue?

arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface's code:

```
/**
 UIView extension - DesignableView.
 */
@objc @IBDesignable open class DesignableView : UIKit.UIView {

  @objc override dynamic public init(frame: CoreGraphics.CGRect)

  @objc required dynamic public init?(coder: Foundation.NSCoder)

  @objc deinit
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @SShahid I don't see the reason why not using an image, anyhow I've edited the code in. Please note that this code is generated using swift binary xcframework. XCode's Interface Builder seemed to be having problem detecting the IBDesignable classes in the binary framework.